# Configuring Apache to not rewrite URLs for FILE + SLASH

Tags: apache, url, configuration, url-rewriting

I have this problem where all URLs like `context/path/file/anything/that/follows` becomes `context/path/file.php/anything/that/follows` or `context/path/file.xml/anything/that/follows`.

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^service/(.*)$ service.php?xyz=1 [L,QSA]
```

which should map any URL starting with `service/...` to `service.php`. Now, problem is, if an XML file named `service.xml` is in the same folder as the `.htaccess`, the URLs are mapped to that file instead. If a PHP file exists, they go to the PHP file. The XML file takes precedence, i.e. if there is both an XML file and a PHP file with the name `service.*` in the directory, the XML file gets chosen.

I have PHP 5.3, Apache 2.x, on Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion). This problem did not previously occur when I had OS X 10.6, So there must be some changes in the configurations provided by Apple. I just cannot figure out what.

Is there a way I could disable this *functoinality*?

Or am I entirely off-track, and donig something stupid?

BTW, this does not relate to mod_rewrite, as enabling or disabling it, or removing the rewrite rule from the `.htaccess` changes anything. The URL `service/my/parameter` still points to `service.xml/my/parameter`, even if mod_rewrite is disabled.

For now, I have just taken the query string out of the url, and parsed it manually inside the PHP file. But I know that is not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) option enabled.

Try to add `Options -MultiViews` in the `<Directory>` section (or .htaccess).

Comment: That indeed was it. Thank you a lot. I did not know about the `MultiViews` option.

Comment: Yes. a quite annoying thing. If you do not need content-negociation you could also remove mod_negociate

Comment: I had this in my user config file on a mac. I am not sure if I put it there, or if it already existed: "Options Indexes MultiViews". I removed the word MultiViews, and that fixed it. Thanks so much !

Comment: Forgot to upvote, since at the time I lacked the reputation to do it :)