# Rewrite all directory requests to a subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I am trying to rewrite all requests made to `/myproj`(or any files inside it) to `/myproj/web` using .htaccess.

The problem I am having is that the requests with a trailing slash (e.g., `/myproj/somefile.php/`) are somehow being rewritten to `/docroot/index.php` instead of `/myproj/web/somefile.php/`.

My `/myproj/.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myproj/web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I do remember that this has something to do with one of the Apache2 modules enabled in your httpd config. The same will happen if you have something similar to `../something.xml/...`. I had this same problem and it drove me nuts until I asked it over here.

Comment: Are there other rules? Particularly rules that route stuff to an index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443649/configuring-apache-to-not-rewrite-urls-for-file-slash). It is the same problem I had, answered by a dear peer over at stackoverflow.

Comment: `Options -MultiViews` didn't help :S

Comment: What about the `mod_negociate` comment?